# Can't change color of graph in Mathematica Manipulate plot

Tags: education

I want to color code my functions with the Plotstyle command shown in the image but it doesn't allow it. Is there any possible way to change the colors? I need to know which graph corresponds to which function

[image]

Comment: it looks like your `PlotStyle` is outside the scope of `Plot`. Notice it had RED color. This means Mathematica does not like where it is.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the `PlotStyle` option inside the `Plot` function, i.e. after the `{x,0,b}`, before closing `Plot`:

```
Manipulate[ Plot[{f[x],l[x],q[x]c[x]},{x,0,b},PlotStyle->{...}], {b,{...}}]
```

`Manipulate` doesn't know about plots, it just know that you are manipulating the value of `b`.